# What is the way to run c program's .exe file compiled on Windows OS to IMX8M Yocto Linux Board

Tags: embedded, cross-platform, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, yocto

I want to run hello.exe file generated on Windows OS platfrom for simpe hello.c file on IMX8M yocto linux board. I am very new to use this board and I am not finding any helping material on the same. Can anyone guide me is it possible or not and where can I find related documents.

If it's not possible, what are the other ways to run .exe generated from any HOST OS to Yocto Linux board.

Comment: You need to clarify if you need cross-compilation or emulation. They are very different concepts to achieve the same goal.If you need to run the same ".exe" generated you'll need a VM. If your "hello.c" is a simple print to console "Hello, world !", you could just the compiler on your yocto board

Comment: Yes. I can use the VM with Linux. But that is not what I required. My project definition is to there is a way to run .exe generated on Window host. The best way if I can find cross compiler tool to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some misunderstanding.

As the host and the device are not the same architecture (x64/ARM) and the same OS (Windows/Linux), you need to cross-compile your code. This is done by using a specific compiler, able to run on your host machine, to generate your binary for your device machine.

If you want to compile an application for your iMX8M from your Windows computer, you will need to find a cross-compiler toolchain able to run on Windows, generating binaries for Linux ARM architecture.

If you use Yocto, you can generate a SDK, which contains a cross-compiler toolchain by using `bitbake <image> -c populate_sdk` or `bitbake <image> -c do_populate_sdk` (depending on your Yocto version).

By default Yocto generates a SDK for a Linux host, so you will need to develop on a Linux OS.

There is aslo a specific meta that helps to generate a SDK for Windows: [meta-mingw](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-mingw/)

Comment: Note that WSLv2 is supported: http://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/dev-manual-start.html#preparing-the-build-host

Comment: Hi PierreOlivier, Can you give me some clarification or steps that how can I compile my .c code on host i.e (Linux) and run it on iMX8M Yocto board. I want to use Yocto board iMX8M as target where I just wanted to run the application I've developed on my Linux host. What environment setup and libraries I needed to achieve the same ?

Comment: I have found following doc. Am I on the right track (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html)